# Change the total price of a product in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

as you see in the image, the cart has two products.

[image]

I want to add some extra charge to the total price of the first product.

Now is 360 I want to add 30 so, the total price will be 390.

I did it by using the `woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal`
filter, but the cart's total price doesn't update.

It shows 560 and not 590, which is what I want.

Does anyone know how could it be done?